# get Date range when there are no date exists in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my query it's working fine.

But i want to get the blank record with the missing date, when there is no record exist for that date range, while fetching data from table.

```
SELECT * from tbl_social where `dCreatedDate` BETWEEN 
DATE_ADD('2015-07-06', INTERVAL 3 DAY) and DATE_SUB('2015-07-06', INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

[image]

if there is no record for date '2015-07-08' i need that date row also in listing.

Thanking you.

Comment: `or dCreatedDate is null`

Comment: yes, if there is no record between these range response should be all the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some changes to the query and bring all that data which is not in this particular range

and also has no date . to do so try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM SELECT * from tbl_social
WHERE  (
            `dCreatedDate` NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-07-06', INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
             AND DATE_ADD('2015-07-06', INTERVAL 3 DAY)
      ) OR  (`dCreatedDate` IS NULL )
```

with `NOT BETWEEN` it will seek those records which dont fit the criteria and with `NULL`  it will see for those records whose `dCreatedDate` is blank and fetch all the data matching both criteria

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i want to return that date and not blank.

Comment: what do you mean by that date and if you dont want blank records then add `NOT` after `is`

Comment: i am fetching '2015-07-06' next and previous 3 days records right. so if there is no record exists between that date ie. if there is no record for '2015-07-08' then i want that date in response means there is no date exists in dCreated date.